# Podio how to retrieve item after triggering item.delete webhook?

Tags: php, podio

Using the Podio API, how can you retrieve an item after it has been deleted?

I have a web hook which is triggered on `item.delete`, however the hook is fired *after* the item is deleted, so I can't retrieve any of the item's data (and therefore can't "sync" the delete to our third-party site).

Is the only way to store a local copy of the app?

Answer (score 0):

Deleted item is deleted, that's main purpose of deleting things :) It's also a requirement in GDPR.

You are getting `item_id` in webhook, so you can "sync" deletion in your third-party system. And "sync" should basically delete object with that `id`.

In case if you need to mark item as deleted but still keep it, I'd suggest you use some category field, call it "status", and set to to value "deleted" if item is not supposed to be used.

Comment: Thanks - this is to sync our contacts to MailChimp, which uses the MD5 of the email address as an `id`, so syncing by `item_id` isn't a possibility. We already have an active/inactive field (which is synced), so just looking to cover all bases.

Comment: Then you need to keep one more mapping: `podio_item_id` <=> `mainchimp_item_id` and use it to delete deleted Podio item

Comment: or, you can use `external_id` while creating podio items, and you can set it to MD5 of email address. Then Podio will return that `external_id` in item.delete hook. But this solution won't work if you modify email value.

Comment: Was hoping there was some kind of pre-delete event so the data could be grabbed before it was gone.